# How do I get in at the glow?

Tags: neo-scavenger

So, I finally got to the glow, but now I'm stuck and not sure what to do. I got the Tracking Bracelet from Hatter already, but I can't get through the entrance still. When I approach the gates, some guards say that the city's on alert right now, so I can't get in. Then some people outside said that they're going to try again later. I've waited outside for a couple days now I think, and I still can't get in. Do I just have to wait? How long?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's as far as I've gotten with writing the plot (@October 2012). The "orange alert" is just there as a plausible in-game reason why you can't get in.

More plot, and access to the DMC proper is on the way, but for now, players are shut out.

Sorry about that!